# How to match object's id:Pk[T] in Anorm?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

How to check if the object was already been saved to database ( e.g. by matching its id)?

Something similar to the following snippet:

```
case class User(id: Pk[Long], name:String) {

    def loaded = id match {
      case NotAssigned => false  
      case Pk(refererId) => true
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, you want:

```scala
import anorm.Id        // if you don't already have import anorm._

case class User(id: Pk[Long], name:String) {
  def loaded = id match {
    case NotAssigned => false  
    case Id(refererId) => true
  }   
}
```